# How define types of objects in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have following code:

```
type Machine = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    tonnage?: number
}

const machines = {
    "machine1": {id: "S01", name: "AnyMachine"} as Machine,
}
```

is possible to indicate that key is string and value is typeof Machine?
Casting as Machine seems to work, but I would like to have less verbose alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
interface MachineHolder {
  [key: string]: Machine;
}

type Machine = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  tonnage?: number
}

const machines: MachineHolder = {
  "machine1": {id: "S01", name: "AnyMachine"},
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
type Machines = {
    [key: string]: Machine;
}

const machines: Machines = {
    "machine1": { id: "S01", name: "AnyMachine" }
}
```

But, depending on what you're trying to do, it might not be necessary.
The Typescript type system is [based on the structure of the types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), so you can just do this and it will work:

```
const machines = {
    "machine1": { id: "S01", name: "AnyMachine" }
}

function fn(machine: Machine) {
    // ...
}

fn(machines.machine1);
```

Here the compiler infers that you're passing the right type even though `machines` isn't defined as a map of `Machine`s.

Comment: Thanks, my intentions are quite strange. I just want to use this as custom typed records and to use typescript tooling to check my types without compiling. I know I should use better tools like database but this is less painless for small datas :)